# ¿Cómo guardar la dirección de memoria de un puntero en un double en C?

Tags: c, punteros, double, memoria

Lo que busco es poder almacenar la dirección de memoria de un puntero de cualquier tipo en una variable en C. ¿Existe algún método para poder obtener la dirección de memoria de un puntero y guardarlo en una variable?  He estado tratando de diversas maneras y no he conseguido tener éxito en ninguna de ellas.

```
double direccion;
//direccion guarda la direccion de memoria de un puntero
int *p_int;
int n=5;
p_int=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

//direccion=&p_int ?? esta es mi duda, que debería poner?

printf("%f\n",direccion);
//se imprime la direccion de memoria de p_int
```

Comment: Como poderse, se puede ... lo que no podrás luego es **usarla para nada**. Es decir, puedes asignarla, pero el valor asignado no será exactamente igual al original ... ¿ Para que quería nadie hacer eso ? Por si tu problema fuera otro.

Comment: Es para desarrollar un compilador, una de las restricciones es trabajar todos los valores como double y para la implementaión de arreglos lo que me pidieron era guardar la direccón de memoria donde apunta el puntero y trabajar el arreglo a partir de eso.

Comment: Que curioso que os fuercen a aprender algo que, te garantizo, no sirve para absolutamente nada. En fin, me estaré quedando obsoleto O_O

Comment: Bueno, y cómo podría asignarla?xd

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, las conversiones de punteros hacia y desde (void *) son siempre válidas. ¿Igual podrías probar por ahí? Es difícil responder si no pones ejemplos de lo que has probado.

Comment: Guardar la direccion de memoria de un puntero no seria redundante?, es decir,  un puntero si no estoy mal ya de por si almacena la direccion de memoria de una variable o me equivoco?, la verdad no uso mucho lenguajes de C pero quiero aprenderlos.

Comment: @Riven. Es usual tener múltiples niveles de punteros. Por ejemplo, puedes tener un puntero a una lista de clientes. Cada elemento de la lista es un puntero a una estructura que contiene los datos del cliente, que a su vez, tiene punteros que llevan al nombre, dirección, etc.

Answer (score 13):

La manera de guardar una dirección de memoria en un `double` es no hacerlo nunca.

[image]

---

Un `double` es un tipo de dato que almacena números en coma flotante de doble precisión, una dirección de memoria es una dirección de memoria.

Una de las operaciones más comunes en un puntero es operar mediante aritmética de punteros la cuál es **MUY** diferente a la aritmética de números en coma flotante. Así que si tienes una formación (1) de la que obtienes dirección del primer elemento (2) la guardas en un `double` (3) y sumas una posición (4), no obtendrás la misma dirección de memoria que si a la dirección del primer elemento (2) le sumas una posición sin haber pasado por double (5):

```
int valores[2] = {1, 2};    // 1
int *primero = valores;     // 2

double NO_HAGAS_ESTO = (double)valores; // 3
NO_HAGAS_ESTO++;                        // 4

int *segundo = primero + 1; // 5
```

De hecho, [los compiladores ni siquiera te dejan convertir un puntero a `double` y viceversa](https://tio.run/##VY67DoJAEEVr9ysmGBJQMEKLklAYraTATg1BdsVNYJcsj4bw7ciGl3aTc8/MndhM4rjr1pTFaYUJHIoSU777uOgXCcoSyRBlJWQRZVrNKdZRg1aS1FHKBSnu9hOO0FgG2K0zJJtc0IwI3vNRmoKCJBXDMpiULVgOQivMq1dK4OqHF@/sBeEpuPm9pQ1cH21p9iMr35qydKg5mC6o@MEUY7przE/ozrKz1P/tjNiY/9NlkSBlJRjsHdR23Rc), porque **NO DEBE HACERSE NUNCA**.

Comment: Te falta un nunca entre el segundo y tercer nunca.

Comment: "Una direccion de memoria es una direccion de memoria", sabias palabras maestro, bueno es broma,  xd, me ha hecho gracia eso de una direccion de memoria es una direccion de memoria,  pero hablando en serio muy buena respuesta voto arriba.

Comment: Estoy mirando tu respuesta en Revisión y no aparece tu nombre. Simplemente dice "Respondida hace 2 horas" y debajo una silueta en blanco. El encabezado dice "Esta es la primera respuesta publicada por un usuario nuevo" ... Wait! Oh, diablos, otras de las trampitas de Revisión, "para ver si estabas prestando atención" ... humm

Answer (score 7):

Como poder, se puede ... pero, por si aún no había quedado claro

## NO LO HAGAS NUNCA

Ahora bien, si por una razón **de vida o muerte**, de **Evento de Extinción Masiva**, o de **Fin de Toda la Vida tal y como la Conocemos** te vieras en la obligación de hacerlo, lo mas simple es usar una `union`:

```
union NO_HACER {
  double dbl;
  int *ptr;
};

int main( void ) {
    int valores[2] = {1, 2};    // 1
    int *primero = valores;     // 2
    union NO_HACER NoHacerlo;
    NoHacerlo.ptr = valores;

    return 0;
}
```

Puesto que todos los *miembros* de la `union` comparten la misma dirección base de memoria, ya podrías acceder tanto a la vista *en* `double` como a la vista *en* `int *` de los mismos datos.

```
NoHacerlo.dbl -> Vista de los datos como si fueran un `double`.
NoHacerlo.ptr -> Vista de los datos como si fueran un `int *`.
```

Comment: Esto puede derivar en comportamiento indefinido. Es comportamiento indefinido leer del miembro inactivo de una `union`. El miembro activo de una una `union` es aquel al que se le asigna valor, el resto permanecen inactivos.

Answer (score 5):

Vaya por delante, por si no ha quedado claro, que NO DEBERIAS HACER ESTO NUNCA. Pero realmente si te empeñas sí que es posible hacerlo, aunque no tenga ningún sentido. En esta respuesta explico cómo se podría y por qué funcionaría y por qué no tiene sentido.

### La teoría

Un puntero es una dirección de memoria. En una arquitectura de 64 bits como las actuales las direcciones de memoria son de 64 bits, lo que significa que un puntero es en el fondo un número de 64 bits (8 bytes).

Un `double` es un formato para guardar números de coma flotante usando 64 bits, según la norma IEEE-754 de precisión doble.

Por tanto tanto el puntero (en una arquitectura de 64 bits) como el `double` son en última instancia números de 64 bits (8 bytes). Desde el punto de vista de su tamaño son compatibles, aunque desde el punto de vista de su significado no lo sean en absoluto.

### El problema

Imagina que has ejecutado el siguiente código:

```
  double direccion;
  //direccion guarda la direccion de memoria de un puntero
  int *p_int;
  int n=5;
  p_int=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

Esto crea dos variables llamadas `direccion` de tipo `double` y `p_int` de tipo puntero. Ambas ocupan 8 bytes como hemos visto antes. Cada una de estas variables estará almacenada en una dirección diferente que podemos obtener con `&direccion` y `&p_int` respectivamente. En la dirección `&direccion` no tenemos ningún valor conocido, porque no hemos asignado aún nada, pero en la dirección `&p_int` sí tenemos un valor, que es el resultado de `malloc()`.

Imaginemos que:

- La variable `direccion` se almacena en `0x00007ffec31aa5d8`
- La variable `p_int` se almacena en `0x00007ffec31aa5d0`
- `malloc()` ha retornado `0x0000000002463260`

Esta situación podríamos representarla gráficamente así:

> [image: Memoria]

Y lo que tú estás preguntando básicamente sería cómo meter el valor `&p_int` en la dirección donde está la variable `direccion`. Es decir, llegar al siguiente resultado:

> [image: Resultado esperado]

Naturalmente el problema es que el número `00007ffec31aa5d0` interpretado como `double` (es decir, decodificado según el estándar IEEE-754) te va a dar un número absurdo (en este caso concreto sale prácticamente cero, del orden de 10<sup>-310</sup>). No obstante sigamos con el juego y supongamos que su valor como double no importa, sólo estamos interesados en meter como sea ese número binario en esa variable.

### Una solución

Una solución es utilizar el siguiente casting (tápense los ojos las almas sensibles):

```
  *((void **)&direccion) = (void *) &p_int;
```

Esto es una barbaridad equivalente a meter a golpes una esfera hasta que quepa dentro de un cubo del mismo volumen. Pero tratemos de entender por qué funciona. Empecemos por el lado derecho. El casting `(void *)` está diciendo al compilador "considera lo que sigue como un puntero sin importar a qué tipo apunta). Así que `&p_int` (el número `0x00007ffec31aa5d0`) es considerado un puntero "sin más" (en este caso contrario sería en realidad un puntero a puntero a int).

Para poder asignar ese valor, considerado como un "puntero sin más" necesitamos que al lado izquierdo de la asignación haya una referencia a un lugar de la memoria que pueda guardar un "puntero sín más" (una variable de tipo `void *`).

Como queremos forzar a que se guarde en la variable `direccion`, que no es de tipo `void*`, forzamos al compilador a que la considere del tipo apropiado haciendo el siguiente truco. Mediante `&direccion` obtenemos la dirección donde está esa variable (sería `0x00007ffec31aa5d8` en nuestro ejemplo). Mediante el castsing `(void **)` forzamos a que esa dirección sea considerada "un puntero a un lugar donde poder guardar un puntero void". Finalmente mediante el `*` de fuera se desreferencia esa dirección.

Todo eso "convence" al compilador de que la asignación es válida y así logras tu antinatural objetivo.

### Resultado

Ya tienes en `direccion` el número que querías. Ahora bien, para poder usarlo como lo que realmente es (un puntero a void) debes volver a usar castings al tipo apropiado. Sin esos castings sería tratado como un `double` y no podrías manejarlo como puntero.

Un ejemplo de código que muestra estas cosas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  double direccion;
  //direccion guarda la direccion de memoria de un puntero
  int *p_int;
  int n=5;
  p_int=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
 
  // Asignacion monstruosa
  *((void **)&direccion) = (void *) &p_int;

  printf("p_int está almacenado en: %p\n", &p_int);
  printf("direccion tiene el valor (visto como puntero): %p\n", *((void **) &direccion));
  printf("direccion tiene el valor (visto como double): %g\n", direccion);

  p_int[0] = 100;
  printf("Elemento [0] accedido a través de direccion: %d\n",
     (**((int ***) &direccion))[0]               // Atención al HORROR
  );
}
```

El horror de la sintaxis ya es una clara indicación de que TODO ESTO NO TIENE SENTIDO Y NO DEBE HACERSE.

Answer (score 4):

para imprimir la dirección de memoria almacenada en un puntero puedes hacer algo tan complicado como esto

```
printf("%p", ptr);
```

No necesitas almacenar la dirección de memoria en otras variables ni hacer otras operaciones extrañas.

No veo necesario advertirte sobre los peligros de hacer las conversiones que propones porque es algo que ya ha quedado claro en otras respuestas